# How to sync 1 TB multimedia data over the net

Tags: sync, ftp, nas, nfs

As an admin, I have the task to sync nearly 1 TB of multimedia data (jpg, tif, bmp images or pdf documents) with three partner over the internet and I'm asking how.
Its nearly 500.000 single files in 50.000 folders I guess.
I also have a 2 TB NAS in a datacenter for the data.
I have tried different tools (usually freeware) to achieve this but none of them really worked.

I prefer the ftp protocol but nfs is also possible. 
I tried FTPbox, but its crashing by the huge amount of data.

Most of the tools I tested (FreeFileSync, FTPbox, PureSync) are crashing or are really slow because of the many files to compare.

Nice would ne a dropbox like client (therefore I tested FTPbox) which can detect modified file by itself and updates them, but I guess even the dropbox client has his problems with the file amount.

Does someone know a tool to sync these huge amount of data?

Comment: Would splitting these up be an option? Have you tried *anything* other than FTP? What OSes are you using? Do you need to keep them *consistantly* synced or is this a one off sort of thing? Does sync need to be single directional or multi directional?

Comment: Splitting is no option I'm afraid. I tried nfs without much success. OS is Windows Server 2008 and a Synology NAS, multi-directional sync and the files need to be constantly up to date. Maybe with a time difference of couple of hours.

Answer (score 2):

The well-known [rsync](http://rsync.samba.org/) tool is designed for this kind of problem. You will need ssh login access (or rsync daemon at the least) to make this work.

Comment: I will try to make it work with Windows, thanks for the hint.